# Unable to get event.stopPropagation(); working within my code

Tags: reactjs, typescript, web

I have the following code which is linked to a text area, but for some reason it is not working as you would expect, the user is still allowed to type into the textarea:

```
  const handleKeyDown = (event: React.KeyboardEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { code, target } = event;
    const { value } = target as HTMLInputElement;

    if (code === 'Enter') {
      if ([...value].filter((word) => word === '\n').length >= DETAIL_MAX_LINES) {
        event.stopPropagation();
      }
    }
  };
```

```
<TextField
        onKeyDown={handleKeyDown}
        ...
/>
```

Any assistance in getting this functionality to work would be fantastic, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use `event.preventDefault()`

```
   if (code === 'Enter') {
      if ([...value].filter((word) => word === '\n').length >= DETAIL_MAX_LINES) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-yevkvk?file=App.tsx)